# how to fix capybara on win7

Tags: ruby, capybara

i'm using capybara for parser and all is fine on my ubuntu. But when i'm running code on win7 capybara just opens an empty window and that's all. I've installed all gems and web driver that capybara gem was asking me. Don't have and idea how to fix this. 
Running page looks like

```
require 'capybara/dsl'

include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
visit 'https://www.google.com.ua/'
```

Comment: What version of Capybara, selenium-webdriver and Firefox are you using?

Comment: 2.7.1 capybara, selenium webdriver 2.53.4, firefox 48.0.1

Comment: Why not using `docker` ?

Comment: cuz i thought docker will be unreasonable in this mini task

Answer (score 0):

Needed to downgrade Firefox to 47.0.1 version. All works fine

Comment: Yes - FF 48+ is only supported with geckodriver and selenium-webdriver v3+ which are not yet ready for full testing use